# Q# Create new project...' resulted in an error

Tags: q#

I'm following these instructions to install Q#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/qsharp-create-first-quantum-development-kit/2-install-quantum-development-kit-code

I have the following SDk and Runtimes
dotnet --list-sdks

3.1.405 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

dotnet --list-runtimes

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I'm running macOS 11.2

I get the following error when trying to create the project (VS Code Version: 1.52.1)
Command 'Q#: Create new project...' resulted in an error (Running the contributed command: 'quantum.newProject' failed.)

Any help on how to proceed or work around to continue much appreciated.

log output below
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.131] [exthost] [info] extension host started
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.150] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.microsoft-authentication {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.microsoft-authentication","_lower":"vscode.microsoft-authentication"},"activationEvent":"onAuthenticationRequest:microsoft"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.150] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/microsoft-authentication/dist/extension.js
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.159] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-auto-launch {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.debug-auto-launch","_lower":"vscode.debug-auto-launch"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.160] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/debug-auto-launch/dist/extension
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.163] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.emmet {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.emmet","_lower":"vscode.emmet"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.163] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/emmet/dist/node/emmetNodeMain
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.175] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.git {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.github","_lower":"vscode.github"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.175] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/main
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.189] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.merge-conflict {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.merge-conflict","_lower":"vscode.merge-conflict"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.189] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/merge-conflict/dist/mergeConflictMain
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.193] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.search-result {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.search-result","_lower":"vscode.search-result"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.193] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/search-result/dist/extension.js
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.246] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.js-debug {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"ms-vscode.js-debug","_lower":"ms-vscode.js-debug"},"activationEvent":"onCommand:extension.js-debug.clearAutoAttachVariables"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.247] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.342] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github-authentication {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.github-authentication","_lower":"vscode.github-authentication"},"activationEvent":"onAuthenticationRequest:github"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.342] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.376] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.github","_lower":"vscode.github"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.376] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/github/dist/extension.js
[2021-02-04 14:25:18.382] [exthost] [info] eager extensions activated
[2021-02-04 14:25:25.961] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode","_lower":"quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode"},"activationEvent":"onCommand:quantum.newProject"}
[2021-02-04 14:25:25.961] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/out/extension
[2021-02-04 14:25:28.828] [exthost] [error] Error: Command failed with ENOENT: npm root -g --prefix /.yo-repository --loglevel error
spawnSync npm ENOENT
at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1041:20)
at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:616:24)
at Function.module.exports.sync (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/execa/index.js:169:25)
at Object.runPackageManager (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/util/repository.js:114:18)
at Object.get nodeModulesPath [as nodeModulesPath] (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/util/repository.js:40:36)
at Function.assign ()
at new Environment (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:257:30)
at Function.createEnv (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:113:12)
at Object.createNewProject (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/out/commands.js:21:22)
at /Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/out/extension.js:64:24
at /Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/out/commands.js:16:9
at _executeContributedCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:701:220)
at _.$executeContributedCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:701:595)
at m._doInvokeHandler (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:892:926)
at m._invokeHandler (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:892:618)
at m._receiveRequest (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:891:252)
at m._receiveOneMessage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:890:6)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:888:136
at l.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:801)
at v.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:233:787)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:1094:104
at l.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:801)
at v.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:233:787)
at t.PersistentProtocol._receiveMessage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:238:1004)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:235:927
at l.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:801)
at p.acceptChunk (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:231:195)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:230:547
at Socket.t (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:240:822)
at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23) quantum.newProject
[2021-02-04 14:26:00.958] [exthost] [error] Error: Command failed with ENOENT: npm root -g --prefix /.yo-repository --loglevel error
spawnSync npm ENOENT
at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1041:20)
at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:616:24)
at Function.module.exports.sync (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/execa/index.js:169:25)
at Object.runPackageManager (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/util/repository.js:114:18)
at Object.get nodeModulesPath [as nodeModulesPath] (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/util/repository.js:40:36)
at Function.assign ()
at new Environment (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:257:30)
at Function.createEnv (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:113:12)
at Object.createNewProject (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/out/commands.js:21:22)
at /Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/out/extension.js:64:24
at /Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode-0.15.2101126940/out/commands.js:16:9
at _executeContributedCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:701:220)
at _.$executeContributedCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:701:595)
at m._doInvokeHandler (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:892:926)
at m._invokeHandler (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:892:618)
at m._receiveRequest (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:891:252)
at m._receiveOneMessage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:890:6)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:888:136
at l.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:801)
at v.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:233:787)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:1094:104
at l.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:801)
at v.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:233:787)
at t.PersistentProtocol._receiveMessage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:238:1004)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:235:927
at l.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:801)
at p.acceptChunk (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:231:195)
at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:230:547
at Socket.t (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:240:822)
at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23) quantum.newProject

Comment: Thanks for your post! This may be an instance of a known bug that was reported to us very recently (https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/issues/848); would you be willing to check the output logs shown in that bug report to see if you're encountering the same issue? Thank you!

Comment: It seems related...[14:25:28.828] [exthost] [error] Error: Command failed with ENOENT: npm root -g --prefix /.yo-repository --loglevel error
spawnSync npm ENOENT
 at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1041:20)
 at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:616:24)
 at Function.module.exports.sync (/Users/richarc/.vscode/extensions/quantum.quant

Comment: Added full log to main question.. not sure how to fly this thing properly ..

Comment: Hi Chris. I just did "$brew install node" and seems to have fixed everything..Thanks very much for help.

Comment: No worries, happy to help! As noted at that bug, node should not be required to use the Quantum Development Kit; we're looking to get that fixed as soon as possible, but I'm glad that installing node works for you as a mitigation in the meantime! Thank you!